# Can I replace an original laptop battery with an OEM battery with higher voltage / power?

Tags: voltage, batteries, battery-charging, laptop, capacity

My original laptop battery is 11.1 V and 74 Wh. It was starting to swell and needed replacement, but I accidentally bought a wrong OEM battery that is 11.4 V and 71 Wh.

Is it safe to proceed and use this OEM battery?

Comment: I would return it and buy the proper battery. I would hope the circuitry is designed well enough that 0.3 V wouldn’t cause a safety issue, but it could definitely cause a functionality issue because of the various safeties built into a laptop. Can’t say for sure though without a lot more info that just isn’t worth gathering.

Comment: In battery terms probably not an issue. But as @JoeMac implied there could be all sorts of other subtleties why it's just not worth using exactly the same part (unless the manufacturer claims compatibility and you believe them).

Comment: Should be OK in itself, per ocrdu's answer. But the other issue : laptops generally talk to the battery's BMS. If the OEM hasn't got that right the laptop may not recognise the battery and may refuse to charge it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over the years, the maximum charging cut-off voltage for Li-ion batteries has gone up a bit, because of improvements, and perhaps a bit of marketing.

The three cells in a (nominally) 11.1V battery pack are usually charged to 4.2 V per cell, the (newer and slightly different) cells in a (nominally) 11.4 V battery pack are usually charged to 4.35 V per cell.

Replacing a 11.4 V battery pack with an 11.1 V battery pack will cause trouble because the cells will be overcharged.

Replacing a 11.1 V battery pack with a 11.4 V battery pack should be OK, but the cells will not be fully charged so you don't get to use their quoted full capacity. On the up side: they will last a bit longer (more charging cycles).

The higher top voltage translates into a slightly higher average voltage over a discharge cycle, but it is very unlikely this will bother your laptop.

Having said that, *the warnings in the comments do apply*, and to be sure, you should either get a different battery pack or get a very good guarantee.